# Skip Glympse wizard view iOS

Tags: c++, ios, send, wizard, glympse

I want to integrate Glympse in my application, but without the wizard view.

In detail: 
After calling the sendTicket() method the application opens an URL which leads to the wizard view of Glympse. Here the user can apply the settings and finally send the Glympse.
To react on a successfully sent Glympse a listener can be added.

But I don't like the wizard view to pop up. I want a method which sends the whole Glympse, i.e. I don't want to "leave" my app.

Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to skip the wizard view, you'll need to use the Glympse Commercial SDK. See a comparison of the differences between that and the Lite SDK which you're currently using here: https://developer.glympse.com/sdk/comparison

Drop us a note using the form on the bottom of that page and we'll send you what you need!

Comment: The link in the answer is no longer valid. Could you give an updated link?

Comment: The Glympse Lite SDK no longer exists. There is only a single SDK available for apps to integrate. Guides and reference material for the client sdk is available here https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/client-sdk